# Hadoop: sockets not supported while copying files to the destination file system on OS X

Tags: java, hadoop, osx-yosemite

I tried to copy files from local file system to the destination file system using the commands "put" or "copyFromLocal", in both cases I got the same issue related to sockets:

```
$ bin/hdfs dfs -put /tmp /user/ks/tmp
15/01/06 04:48:11 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
put: /tmp/com.apple.launchd.OKmBZ211il/Render (Operation not supported on socket)
put: /tmp/com.apple.launchd.Z0DmcBDI4x/Listeners (Operation not supported on socket)
put: /tmp/com.rim.BBCM (Operation not supported on socket)
put: /tmp/com.rim.BBDD (Operation not supported on socket)
put: /tmp/com.rim.BBDE (Operation not supported on socket)
```

Why does not operation supported on sockets?